# enforce package declaration check in javac

Tags: java, eclipse, build, package, javac

When I have a package declaration that does not match with the directory structure Eclipse will present me an error like "The declared package "package-name" does not match the expected package "directory-path". That's perfectly fine. But not everybody in my project uses Eclipse.

Is there a way to do this check with javac in the build process?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse verifies the package name against the directory hierarchy in which your source files resides.

However, there isn't any such functionality available with `javac`, in my opinion. You'll have to resort to the basic error which your culprit class will throw:

```
/* ClassA with package statement */
package com.example;

public class ClassA {

}
```

And now if you place another class which uses in the same package and if you don't write the package statement in it :

```
/* ClassB without package statement */
import com.example.ClassA;

public class ClassB {

}
```

You will get the following error in your compilation logs, pointing out the culprit class :

```
$ javac -d . ClassA.java
$ javac -d . ClassB.java
ClassB.java:1: package com.example does not exist
import com.example.Circle;
                  ^
```

Hope that helps!